# Can I do an IF Statement in Access with nothing for false expression

Tags: ms-access, if-statement

I am trying to add an if statement to my Access query where if the month length is equal to 0 it makes the total volume equal to the annualized volume. Below is what I've tried. It keeps asking me to give the term length however so I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
IIf([TERM_LENGTH]=0,[ProcMWh]=[AMWh])

IIf([TERM_LENGTH]="0",[ProcMWh]=[AMWh], [ProcMWh])

IIf([TERM_LENGTH]="0",[ProcMWh]=[AMWh], "")
```

Comment: Use `=IIf([TERM_LENGTH]=0,[AMWh],Null)`

Comment: What value should be returned "if the month length is _not_ equal to 0"?

Comment: hmmm I tried this but it still gives me the pop up to enter the term length...

Comment: Remove the [ ]. (Hard to tell what you're asking.) IIRC, brackets will prompt user for input.

Comment: the error means the access query designer(?) cannot find [TERM_LENGTH].  We need more information on your table structure to diagnose the problem.  Is TERM_LENGTH] a public variable?